# Azure Functions Application Insight - Unable to obtain TelemetryConfiguration in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, serilog

I am trying to configure Serilog Application Insights sink in my C# Azure Function following this documentation:
https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights

Here is part of my DI initialization in Startup.cs:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

    var Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "local.settings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables()
        .Build();


    builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>((sp) =>
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()      
            .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(TelemetryConfiguration.Active, TelemetryConverter.Traces, Serilog.Events.LogEventLevel.Information)
            .CreateLogger();
   }
```

During configuration I need to obtain TelemetryConfiguration object. Everything works just well when I use TelemetryConfiguration.Active singleton. However this approach is marked as deprecated and it is suggested to use either `serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>()` or `TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault()`

Neither of this approaches work and when I use them I don't see any data floating into Application Insights service.

Please how could I obtain TelemetryConfgiuration in supported non deprecated way, so I can use it when constructing serilog sink?

Note: I need to use serilog as I am configuring multiple sinks.

Value for APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING in app settings is set correctly and I run .NET 6 Azure Function using v4 runtime.

Function logging code (trying both approaches, with default logger as well as serilog logger):

```
 public class Topic1_Trigger: ITopic1_Trigger
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Topic1_Trigger> _logger;
        public IConfiguration _configuration { get; }

        public Topic1_Trigger(ILogger<Topic1_Trigger> log, IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _logger = log;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        [FunctionName("Topic1_Trigger")]
        public async Task Run(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("%TOPIC_NAME%", "%TOPIC_SUB%", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage mySbMsg,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
        {
            var topicName = _configuration.GetValue<string>("TOPIC_NAME");
            Log.Information("Recevied Msg:{SBMessageId} Topic: {TopicName} Content: {SBMessageContent}, {LogEvent}, {QueueName},{State}", mySbMsg.MessageId, topicName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mySbMsg.Body.ToString()),null,null,"MSG RECEIVED");
            Log.Error("Test_Serilog");
            _logger.LogTrace("Test_DefaultLogger");
```

Local settings json:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    ...
    "APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING": "<Connection string copied from portal>"
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe this github issue can help
https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights/issues/121

Comment: Please share your `local.settings.json` file.

Comment: @Harshitha as I mentioned it contains value for APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING, but I included part of the local.settings.json file in my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to log Traces to `Application Insights` using `TelemetryConfiguration`

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.12.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Extensions.Logging" Version="3.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Created a new file `Startup.cs`.

Followed the code from the same [link](https://github.com/serilog-contrib/serilog-sinks-applicationinsights#using-with-azure-functions) which you have provided (used  `TelemetryConfiguration`).

***My `Startup.cs`:***

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Extensions.Logging;
using System.IO;


[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(SerilogAppInsights.Startup))]

namespace SerilogAppInsights
{
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            FunctionsHostBuilderContext context = builder.GetContext();

            var Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(context.ApplicationRootPath, "local.settings.json"), optional: true, reloadOnChange: false)
                        .AddEnvironmentVariables()
                .Build();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILoggerProvider>((sp) =>
            {
                Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(sp.GetRequiredService<TelemetryConfiguration>(), TelemetryConverter.Traces)
                    .CreateLogger();
                return new SerilogLoggerProvider(Log.Logger, true);

            });
        }
    }
}
```

Run the Application.

[image]

- Execute the Function with the above URL.

[image]

- Check the traces in the `Application Insights` => `Transaction search`.

[image]

Comment: thank you for validating @Harshitha. I have very same setup and still when obtaining TelemtryConfiguration thru service provider I see not traces. Please can you confirm you are using serilog logger to trace, ```Log.Information("message content")```

Comment: Yes in my function I have log traces with log information and log warning. You can see the same in the given image.

Comment: Could you please share your function and logging code.

Comment: thank you @Hashitha I added function/logging code into original post

Comment: Have you set the `ServiceBusConnection` String in `local.settings.json` as  well?

Comment: In function after `ServiceBusReceivedMessage mySbMsg` add ILogger _logger.

Comment: And log your Messages as `_logger.LogInformation("Your message");